# Xml syntax error 527 in delphi while using Tibxuspsship component

Tags: xml, delphi

When I generate the shipping package label using `Tibxuspsship` component in Delphi, I get an XML syntax error.
I have tried sample for generating shippinglabel for usps in PDF format. I have used the below code for generating the shipping label.

```
procedure TfrmUspsAdd.BBPrintClick(Sender: TObject);
var nI,ntype : integer;
    url,iUspsLabelFile : string;
    Services : int64;
begin
  url := 'http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll';
 // url := 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll';

  uspsship.Config('Certify=true');
  uspsrates.USPSServer   := url;
  uspsrates.USPSUserId   := 'ABCD';
  uspsrates.USPSPassword := 'XYZ123';

  USPSShip.SenderFirstName := 'John';
  uspsship.SenderLastName  := 'Smith';
  uspsship.SenderAddress1  := '475 LEnfant Plaza, SW';
  uspsship.SenderCity      := 'Washington';
  uspsship.SenderState     := 'DC';
  uspsship.SenderZipCode   := '20260';

  uspsship.RecipientFirstName := 'Jane';
  uspsship.RecipientLastName  := 'Smith';
  uspsship.RecipientAddress1  := '8 Wildwood Drive';
  uspsship.RecipientCity      := 'Old Lyme';
  uspsship.RecipientState     := 'CT';
  uspsship.RecipientZipCode   := '06371';

  uspsship.LabelImageType :=  TibxUspsshipLabelImageTypes(3);  // for .Pdf format

  uspsship.PackageCount   := 1;

  uspsship.PackageShippingLabelFile[0]  := 'C:\DBS\Temp\test_label.pdf';
  uspsship.LabelOption       := '1';
  uspsship.PackageHeight[0]  := 2;
  uspsship.PackageLength[0]  := 2;
  uspsship.PackageWeight[0]  := '2 lbs 2 oz';
  uspsship.PackageSignatureType[0] := stNoSignatureRequired;
  ntype := 72;
  uspsship.ServiceType           := TibxUspsshipServiceTypes(nType);
  try
  uspsship.GetPackageLabel();
  except
  end;
  label3.Caption := uspsship.PackageTrackingNumber[0];
end;
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: What is the exact error message? The error code is not universal, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TfrmUspsAdd.BBPrintClick(Sender: TObject);
var nI,ntype : integer;
    url,iUspsLabelFile : string;
    Services : int64;
begin
  url := 'http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll';
 // url := 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll';

  uspsship.Config('Certify=true');
  uspsship.USPSServer   := url;
  uspsship.USPSUserId   := 'ABCD';
  uspsship.USPSPassword := 'XYZ123';

  USPSShip.SenderFirstName := 'John';
  uspsship.SenderLastName  := 'Smith';
  uspsship.SenderAddress1  := '475 LEnfant Plaza, SW';
  uspsship.SenderCity      := 'Washington';
  uspsship.SenderState     := 'DC';
  uspsship.SenderZipCode   := '20260';

  uspsship.RecipientFirstName := 'Jane';
  uspsship.RecipientLastName  := 'Smith';
  uspsship.RecipientAddress1  := '8 Wildwood Drive';
  uspsship.RecipientCity      := 'Old Lyme';
  uspsship.RecipientState     := 'CT';
  uspsship.RecipientZipCode   := '06371';

  uspsship.LabelImageType :=  TibxUspsshipLabelImageTypes(3);  // for .Pdf format

  uspsship.PackageCount   := 1;

  uspsship.PackageShippingLabelFile[0]  := 'C:\DBS\Temp\test_label.pdf';
  uspsship.LabelOption       := '1';
  uspsship.PackageHeight[0]  := 2;
  uspsship.PackageLength[0]  := 2;
  uspsship.PackageWeight[0]  := '2 lbs 2 oz';
  uspsship.PackageSignatureType[0] := stNoSignatureRequired;
  ntype := 72;
  uspsship.ServiceType           := TibxUspsshipServiceTypes(nType);
  try
  uspsship.GetPackageLabel();
  except
  end;
  label3.Caption := uspsship.PackageTrackingNumber[0];
end;
```